# Adding security (SSL) to a Spring web service

Tags: spring-ws

I've followed this guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/ to create a web service using Spring Rest. But now I need to add a SSL to the communication, I've tried following this other guide: http://www.radcortez.com/ssl-tls-rest-server-client-with-spring-and-tomee/ but a lot of code is in the `web.xml` file, wich the first guide said isn't used. I imagine now it's supposed to be in some kind of annotation. I would really appreciate some help with this!

Comment: Try http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#howto-configure-ssl

Comment: This seems to be it. But where can I find this application.properties?